# Create a Custom Control using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to do some research into this, but I haven't yet found anything related to this, so I've come here in hopes that someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Is there any way at all that we can create our own HTML Elements?

I've seen a Custom ComboBox that was created using Javascript months back, but cannot find it anymore.

Basically, I'd like to create my own 'Control', that I can use for my pages. Maybe something that can be just 'plugged in' (although not a requirement). Any thoughts/ideas/advice/links?

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at how jQuery UI guys do it?

Comment: Question seems a little broad. A custom control can be created using so many different methods. Creating divs, styling them, adding event listeners to mutate elements, add attributes, sending data. Without knowing exactly what "control" you want to create this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: @Gary G - Yeah, I tried to make it as broad as possible. The reason being is that I'm not sure how many ways there are, and how I would go about it, so I didn't want to limit the question in any way. Re, "Control", Well, I guess, any type of input element. Like a Button, TextField, ComboBox, SplitButton etc. But again, I don't want to limit to just those controls. I'm not really after any specific control, just something that will lead me into the right direction, (even in just a single area), from there I can learn more

Comment: @Jan Hančič - Thanks! I will check out the jQuery site. That didn't even occur to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write a JQuery plug-in but don't know where to start, have a look at this site: http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate

He's written a boilerplate code for a jquery plug-in, with plenty of comments explaining what to do and how to expand it. It should make a good starting point for you.